# how do i limit the autocomplete feature on google places to keywords

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Using the Google places java-script library at the Google provided sample :
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

I am trying to get only results like 'Mexican restaurants', 'fast food' , 'florist' etc and not establishments or cities/countries.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en#adding_autocomplete), it is not possible. You can only limit the results to the type of "establishment" which means

> instructs the Place service to return only business results.